# Nim: `Unable to process type: nnkBracketExpr` when unmarshal to type with Table[string, seq[string]]

Tags: nim-lang

The following type `Response`:

```
type
  Response* = object
    name: string
    vers: string
    features: Table[string, seq[string]]
```

which I'm trying to unmarshal a json to:

```
  let json = parseJson(text)
  let test = to(json, Response)
```

However `to(json, Response)` is throwing the following exception:

```
Error: unhandled exception: false Unable to process type: nnkBracketExpr
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, do I need to specify the `features` Table in another way?

Thanks

Comment: I tested the above with some dummy response data and it works as expected. See here: https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3ztN

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example